# Is it possible to store body of class method in a variable?

Tags: php

If I have a this kind of class:

```
class MyClass {
    protected function method1() {
      // Method body
    }
}
```

Can  I somehow save body of this method in variable, so I could pass it down the application?

For example like this:

```
class MyClass {
    function __construct() {
        $var = // body of method1
        $something = new AnotherClass($var);
    }

    protected function method1($arg1, $arg2) {
      // Method body
    }
}


class AnotherClass {
    function __construct($var) {
        $var($this->arg1, $this->arg2);
    }
}
```

I something like this possible?

Comment: Wha? Why not extend the class?

Comment: Because AnotherClass is already extending something for example :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass the *body*, but you can pass a `callable` reference to that function:

```
...
new AnotherClass(array($this, 'method1'))
...

class AnotherClass {
    function __construct(callable $var) {
        $var($this->arg1, $this->arg2);
    }
}
```

In this case the method is `protected`, so `AnotherClass` can't call it directly. You can use anonymous functions then:

```
...
new AnotherClass(function ($arg1, $arg2) { return $this->method1($arg1, $arg2); })
...
```

The `callable` type hint and `$this` in anonymous functions only works since PHP 5.4 and anonymous functions are only available in 5.3+. For any previous versions the workaround would be more or less pretty complex. I doubt how good a solution this really is though, other design patterns may be a lot more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use anonymous functions:

```
$self = $this;
$var = function($arg1, $arg2) use (&$self) {
    $self->method1($arg1, $arg2);
};
```

So full example:

```
class MyClass {
    function __construct() {
        $self = $this;
        $var = function($arg1, $arg2) use (&$self) {
            $self->method1($arg1, $arg2);
        };        
        $something = new AnotherClass($var);
    }

    protected function method1($arg1, $arg2) {
      // Method body
    }
}
```